# Window.location not working in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, url, location

I'm trying to put current page URL into a variable.  I have tried this (alert just to see if it's working):

```
var currenturl = window.location.href;
alert(currenturl);
$(".sign-txt").html(currenturl);
```

Then I tried the jquery version

```
var currentPageUrl = $(location).attr('href');
alert(currentPageUrl);
```

Both of these work on Internet Explorer, but not Chrome or Firefox.

I'm very new to javascript etc and I've searched this to death and can't find an answer that works. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I tested both in chrome. Its working fine. and for sure first onw should work in both